# Use rgba with tkinter

Tags: tkinter, transparency

Does there is any way to use alpha in color of widgets available in tkinter

**Code**

```
button = Button(root,text="Click",color="#1a1a1a50")

Color="#rrggbbaa"
```

Comment: I don't think #rrggbbaa is a supported format in tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, tkinter doesn't support the alpha channel for individual widgets.

Answer (score -1):

While this doesn't have anything to do with the color attribute, it is at least a workaround you can use to achieve the transparency you're looking for.

As of Tcl/Tk 8.5, you can use PNG images with transparency.
I'm using them for the buttons on a find panel in one of my programs here:
[image]

The most you'll need to get this working is a PhotoImage:

```py
import tkinter as tk

button = tk.Button(parent, text='', default="normal", border=0, width=16, height=16)
button.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="transparency.png") # store for reference
button.configure(image=button.image)
button.pack()
```